# White Space at bottom only on firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

This website: https://aponte-systems.com/secure/# in Goolge Chrome doesn’t have a final white line, but on FIREFOX it have. I have read some other questions related and try to implement some solution related with other similar cases but it haven’t been resolve.

Someone have any idea how to debug this line or fixed?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a class `.logo` in this div `#chatstack-container` which gives a `padding-top` even if there is nothing inside on that div.

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    padding-top: 9px !important;
}
```

**Solution:**

Remove that class or set `padding-top:0` to the `.logo`

**Example:**

```
.chatstack-container.logo{
padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```